# Same code huge performance difference in different gcc compilers

Tags: c++, performance

Trying to understand the cause of the performance difference.
I'm reading a ~70M file with the function below.
Running the code with:
gcc 4.4.6 takes less than a second
gcc 3.2.3  takes more than 6 minutes

Most of the time is spend in the assign part.
What was changed to make this speed difference between the 2 compilers ?

```
bool ReadFile(const string& path, string& file_data)
{
    ifstream ifs(path.c_str(), ifstream::in | ifstream::ate);
    if (!ifs) return false;
    int size = ifs.tellg();
    if (size==0) return false;
    ifs.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    file_data.assign((istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)),
       istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    return true;
}
```

Comment: *"with the function below."*. it is missing.

Comment: We need the code AND the compilation flags to provide any reasonable answer.

Comment: Did you compile both code with optimizations turned on?  Is the older GCC using an older standard library version?  FWIW, you should really upgrade.  GCC is on version 9 now and 4.4.6 only has experimental support for C++11 which you should really be using.

Comment: gcc 3.2.3 probably don't have the move semantic, BTW godbolt and wandbox don't have gcc3.2 support, too old :$

Comment: @MartinMorterol Nothing is being moved here.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes both with optimizations turned on. I know I should use a newer compiler I'm just curious what's the cause for this huge difference

Comment: Are you using `file_data` after calling the method? Maybe the newer gcc realizes that it is a dead code (if result is not used) and optimized the whole thing out?

Comment: @helospark it's not the case it actually reads the file in both

Comment: Its a pity that compiler explorer do not support such [old version of gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/p45POQ). Anyway it looks like that problem is hidden somewhere deeper in library.

Comment: Since you are using `std::string`, you should `reserve` space (since you know the size).  The `reserve` will reduce the number of times the string memory is reallocated (which is causing a lot of your slowdown).

Comment: I actually used reserve initially but I saw no performance difference and read online that assign ignores reserve (can't find the source atm) so dropped it. Do you think my source was wrong and reserve is still needed here?

Answer (score 3):

Could you try tweak a bit this code (one extra line):

```cpp
bool ReadFile(const string& path, string& file_data)
{
    ifstream ifs(path.c_str(), ifstream::in | ifstream::ate);
    if (!ifs) return false;
    int size = ifs.tellg();
    if (size==0) return false;
    ifs.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    file_data.reserve(size);
    file_data.assign((istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)),
       istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    return true;
}
```

and do measurement again
In second attempt you can try this:

```cpp
bool ReadFile(const string& path, string& file_data)
{
    ifstream ifs(path.c_str(), ifstream::in | ifstream::ate);
    if (!ifs) return false;
    int size = ifs.tellg();
    if (size==0) return false;
    ifs.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    file_data.resize(size);
    return ifs.read(&file_data[0], size);
}
```

Comment: Your second suggestion is fast. I used 
ostringstream contents;
contents << ifs.rdbuf();
file_data = contents.str();
to overcome the slowness but still wonder how come there is such a huge difference when using istreambuf_iterator

Comment: I'm suspecting that iterator version resizes string as data are growing. Now if capacity of string is to small then reallocation is needed (copy data). Now depending on strategy when and how much capacity of `std::string` should be changed, there might be a huge perforce difference. For example if (this is assumption) old library changes string capacity by constant amount and new library version scales capacity by some factor, performance difference for 70MB can be so big. Forcing allocating large amount of memory once prevents coping memory leading to large performance gain.

Comment: Now in first attempt `assign` method might discard initial capacity and that is why it didn't help. All this should be verified - somewhere I have some code where I'm feeding `std::base_string` with custom allocator which logs how `std::base_string` manages a memory.